# Building OpenSceneGraph 3.4 from source Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, cmake

I have looked into installing the latest stable release of osg: OpenSceneGraph-3.4.0.zip. I can easily install osg using Ubuntu Software centre by searching for openscenegraph and selecting "3D scene graph, utilities and examples (binaries)" to install. only problem is it does not allow me to do the latest stable release. It does only 3.2. SO only way seems to do building from source using CMake. I am new to building from source and tried to find online guide for 2 days but couldn't. Could someone tell me what are the detailed steps to building osg3.4? Or just link to such a tutorial?

Comment: I found a couple of PPAs that have binaries for OpenSceneGraph 3.4. Would that work for you?

Comment: @edwinksl Sure! Thanks. Also if you could just give the exact commands to install, though i should be able to guess more or less.

Comment: Sure, I wrote an answer. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, OP is open to using PPAs instead of building from source.

The [OpenMW PPA](https://launchpad.net/~openmw/+archive/ubuntu/openmw) provides OpenSceneGraph 3.4 as it is one of OpenMW's dependencies. To install OpenSceneGraph 3.4, you run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openmw/openmw
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openscenegraph-3.4
```

Comment: Wow! thanks, it worked. An extra step in middle `sudo apt-get update` might be added.

Comment: @user_1_1_1 Ah yeah, I forgot about that. :)

Comment: I had just a slight doubt. I have installed the software but in future a new version comes out, and i want to uninstall 3.4 and install the newer version. So how to uninstall if needed? I tried `sudo apt-get remove --purge openscenegraph` hoping certainly that osg is removed. But then i typed in `osgversion` and got output: `OpenSceneGraph Library 3.4.0`. It was still there!

Comment: If the OpenMW PPA updates its OpenSceneGraph package, then you can just keep using it. Otherwise, if you want to upgrade OpenSceneGraph using other means, I would first remove the PPA using `ppa-purge`, which would then revert your OpenSceneGraph back to the version in the official repos (version 3.2 as of now); see http://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed for details. Then you can proceed to upgrade OpenSceneGraph using whatever means you desire.

Comment: Got it, thanks! `sudo ppa-purge ppa:openmw/openmw`